# Reading from text file and give score if word is correct

Tags: java, file, text

I have  a list of fruit names in a text file.
A fruit name is displyed in reverse order everytime you press a button.
A user should crack the fruit name and write it in a  text field.
When the user presses the button, the word should be verified in the text file list of fruit names.
if the fruit name supplied by the user is correct, the user should get a score and continue with another fruit name.if it is in incorrect the score remains the same.

I am struggling with giving a score every time the fruit name is correct.
here is my java code function, please help:

```
public int scoreWord() {
    int scores = 0;
    String filePath = "C:\\names.txt";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(filePath);

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        list.add(scan.next());

        for (Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String ss = correct_word.getText();
            String s = it.next();

            for (String list1 : list) {
                if (s.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains((ss))) {
                    scores = scores + 1;
                } else {
                    int newScore = scores;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return scores;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better separate the different responsibilities in your code. What I mean is: there is **absolutely** no need to read the same text file **over and over** again. Its content will **not** change while a user is playing this game.

In that sense: you should **first** read the content of that file (somehow like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Files/Java_Files_readAllLines_Path_path_Charset_cs_.htm) for example). Then you put that information into some `List<String>` or maybe `Set<String>`. And later on, while the user is playing, you simply check the user input against the information that you **previously** acquired by reading your file!

In other words, you:

1. Create a new method that reads that names.txt; and returns a List/Set of the fruit names
2. Then pass that data structure to your scoring method to do its job

Edit; some more code to get you going:

```
Set<String> fruitNames = fetchNamesFromFile("C:\\names.txt");
...
String userGuess = ... the value provided by the user
String normalizedGuess = userGuess.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
if (fruitNames.contains(normalizedGuess)) {
  ... then user guessed correctly ...
```

And the method for fetching:

```
Set<String> fetchAllNamesFromFile(String fname) throws IOException {
   Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
   return new HashSet<>(Files.readAllLines(fname, charset);
 }
```

or something alike (please note: this is just written down, not run through a compiler - it is meant to give you some ideas to work with; not to do the all the coding work for you!)

Of course, the assumption here is that your input file looks like

```
fruit1
fruit2
...
```

and so on. If your input data looks differently, then more work is required.

Comment: I put up some more code. But please understand that we are not here to do your homework for you. This is meant as some inspiration, not as solution to all the challenges you are facing here!

Comment: Thanks. This will help me indeed.